# find the intersection of a curve and a line in three.js

Tags: three.js, bezier

I have a 2D QuaraticBezierCurve, and I'm looking for ways to obtain y coordinates from it given an x value. I understand that it's parametric, so I can easily get x and y from t, but that doesn't achieve my goal of getting y (or a set of y's) from a given x.

I thought that maybe there might be a built-in function to identify intersections (sort of like `geogebra`), which I could use to either find the intersections of my curve with a vertical line (or even my curve with a yz plane)... but I can only find functions which calculate the distance from a line or a plane to a point. I've looked at possible solutions using rays, too, but they don't seem to do what I want either.

Without diving into the Bezier math manually (which I can do, but is much less elegant), is there some more direct way of finding these intersection points?

Comment: As a workaround, you can call `.getSpacedPoints( N )` and approximate your 2D curve as a polyline (a series of piecewise-linear segments).

Comment: You don't need three.js for this. You just need to find the intersection between a quadratic curve and a straight line. That has a normal, basic maths solution. Rotate your curve so that the first point is on (0,0) and your last point on (..., 0) and then just use the quadratic formula to find the roots (https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#intersections covers line/line, line/curve, and curve/curve)

Comment: But the quadratic bezier curve is, despite its name, not a straight y=ax2 + bx + c quadratic function.  In fact it's not a function at all, since the same x can have multiple y values, as the curve can double back on itself.  The bezier formulas are parametric, and resist that direct sort of algebraic solution.